# How to host multi layered directories of properties using spring-cloud-config and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to host a file structure like below using Spring Cloud Config+spring boot

dev,uat etc are the profiles

```
c:config\

defaults.pprops
common.props

c:config\dev\

a.props
b.props
c.props

c:config\uat\

a.props
b.props
c.props
```

That is the monolith application approach of keeping properties, which suites our project for the time being.

1) How to Host such in spring-config-cloud server ?

2) How to read them in client ? As there will be various rest end points for different folders (if possible)

3) How to read all properties under a directory like *.props

AT present my bootstrap.props is a generic one
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:7070/ [ This does not work now, as the properties are no longer shared in only a single folder]
spring.application.name=xyz,abc,efg

Keeping only application.props, and various application-${profiles} are making the property files very large for a monolith application. Planning to break it in individual structu

Comment: Do you have a single application? Can you create folders for different applications and then having uat and dev sub-folders under each of them.

Comment: Yes I have a single application, otherwise it would have been what you're suggesting. I have a monolith application and properties are layered as I have mentioned above, just like a normal hierarchical approach. 
I want 
1) to expose them as a REST using spring-cloud-config.
2) Read all properties in one go similar to *.properties, so that I can add new properties any time
3)How  does spring-cloud-config client read them ?